# Origen y significado alegórico de la expresión "poner a alguien de vuelta y media"

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

Según el DLE:

> [**poner** a alguien **de vuelta y media**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c4efaPO#AWbUYjB)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Tratarlo mal de palabra, llenarlo de improperios.

Esta frase se usa cuando insultas a alguien o hablas mal de él, y se viene usando desde hace bastante tiempo. El caso más antiguo que he encontrado (negritas mías):

> *Quedaron tan amostazados que, ya que fuera de allí no se atrevían a dar tras mí, en el púlpito cuando predicaban **me ponían de vuelta y media**.*
>
> San Juan Bautista de la Concepción (Juan García López), "Memoria de los orígenes en la descalcez trinitaria", c 1607 (España).

Y un ejemplo reciente para demostrar que sigue siendo válida:

> *El inventor de los refranes no debía de tener muy buen concepto de Dios, porque **lo pone de vuelta y media**: "Dios da legañas al que no tiene ojos", "Dios da mocos al que no tiene pañuelos". Vamos, que Dios no da ni una.*
>
> Varios autores, "El club de la Comedia Presenta Ventajas de ser incompetente y otros monólogos de humor", 2001 (España).

Esta frase se suele usar igual que cuando dices que [has puesto a alguien a parir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TdpEAZG#CCPLT84). Sin embargo, en este último caso el significado alegórico está claro: has insultado a una embarazada y le has causado tal disgusto que se le ha adelantado el parto. En el dicho que nos atañe, ¿por qué hablar mal de alguien es ponerlo de vuelta y media? ¿A qué hace alusión esa "vuelta y media"?

Answer (score 2):

De la página https://www.1de3.es/2012/07/07/poner-de-vuelta-y-media/

¿Sabías por qué PONER DE VUELTA Y MEDIA es criticar?

Ponemos de vuelta y media a aquél o a aquello que censuramos o criticanos.

En el Vocabulario de refranes (1627) del maestro Gonzalo de Correas se lee: «A vuelta y media, torrezno fuera» en alusión a lo poco que tarda el tocino en convertirse en torrezno.

En uso metafórico, poner de vuelta y media a alguien es sacarle defectos y criticar sus acciones cambiando la opinión acerca de él en muy poco tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

En México se usa un modismos muy similar, no exclusivamente al insultar a alguien​ sino más bien para denotar que en un debate -verbal o escrito- uno de los participantes ha apabullado a otro con la solidez de sus argumentos, casi al punto de *dejarlo en ridículo* el modismos es

> darle/ponerle  una revolcada/un revolcón a tu oponente

O bien

> darle una arrastrada/ponerle una arrastrada

Que es casi equivalente a la "vuelta y media" con la connotación adicional de haberlo humillado y ensuciado en el proceso.

También aplica en cualquier competencia, por ejemplo deportiva, cuando uno de los contrincantes es muy superior al otro, donde también se usa el universal "vuelta y media", por ejemplo

> "La selección alemana le ***dio una arrastrada*** a la selección de Brasil, anotandole 5 goles a cero en los cuartos de final de la copa del mundo."

Supongo que es una alegoría a un enfrentamiento físico a golpes donde de un bien propinado gancho a la mandíbula hace girar al oponente, (y en el caso de la *revolcada o arrastrada* algo similar a la celebración de Aquiles al vencer a Héctor de Troya en el clímax de *la iliada* )

Cómo sea la vuelta y media tiene connotación de ser un enfrentamiento mas parejo, donde la sorpresa tiene más que ver con el giratorio desenlace =)

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! La idea de que fuera algo físico (hacer que tu oponente dé una vuelta y media al darle un puñetazo) también se me había ocurrido. Lo malo es que igualmente también se me ocurren otras alegorías, por lo que esperaba que las respuestas tuvieran algo más que suposiciones y se basaran en documentación fiable, más teniendo en cuenta que es una expresión muy antigua (se usaba ya en el siglo XVII). En todo caso, resultan interesantes las variedades regionales de México, no las conocía.

Answer (score 0):

Por acá se diría:

- Se las canté claritas.
- Se las cantaron claritas.

> **Cantarlas claritas**:  Decir la verdad; hablarle duramente  a otro; increpar; reprender.

Similar a:

> **Cantar las cuarenta**: Significa reñir a alguien, con razón, por algo que ha hecho mal. El acusado no puede defenderse porque sabe que se ha comportado mal.

Es apabullar a alguien mediante un reto, es decir, **lo pusieron en su lugar** porque **no se las mandó a decir con nadie**.

En lo deportivo se diría algo como: **Lo paseó/Los pasearon**, similar a **le pegó un baile/Les pegaron un baile** o más neutral **recibió/recibieron un baile**.

Hay otras más vulgares o coloquiales pero pueden herir susceptibilidades.

Hay otras frases que tienen relación con daño físico por golpes como en: "Le sacaron cresta **y media**" o lo levantaron a patás(patadas) en la raja(culo) que podría tener un parentezco con el no físico "**le diste/les dieron un levante**" o lo repasaron.

No creo haber escuchado "lo puso de vuelta y media", suena antiguo, pero por acá es dejar a alguien desconcertado al decirle improperios o coloquialmente "pararle los carros".

> **Parar los carros** Locución verbal. Reprobar, encarar y retar, llamarle la atención a alguien por una conducta inapropiada.